# An If Else function is not performing the else

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google app script.  I am attempting to create a basic function.  This is what I have so far:

```
function PRQ(a,b)
{
  if(b=4)
  {
    return a*2
  }
  else 
  {
    return a*3
  }
}
```

This is the result of with b=4 and b not equal to 4:

```
a   b       
5   3       10
5   4       10
```

It is seeing the request to double the value in "a" but not the request to triple it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `=` is for assignment `==` or `===` is to check results

Answer (score 2):

You are using **=** within if statement,It will never execute to get desired result.

Here is working snippet:

```
function PRQ(a,b)
{
var result;
  if(b==4)
  {
        return a*2;
  }
  else 
  {
    return a*3;
  }

}

function main(){
PRQ(5,3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using = instead of ==. = is assignment operator so your if condition always holds true in the code and it always returns a * 2.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  That worked perfectly!